# What is the difference between managed object context save and refreshObject:mergeChanges:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Hello what's the difference between

```
  [self.context refreshObject:site mergeChanges:YES];
```

and

```
  [self.context save:nil];
```

Sometimes I use them both, sometimes I use only `save`. It works in both cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-save:` saves the changes you've made to any managed object in the context. This means they get flushed to the persistent store coordinator, which then writes them to the persistent store, which writes them to disk (assuming a disk-backed store).

On the other hand, `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` does something quite different. It *reads* the current state of the object from the persistent store coordinator (which reads from the persistent store, and so on). Passing `YES` for `mergeChanges` means to keep any local modifications to the object intact and only update the fields that weren't changed. This is pretty much the opposite of `-save:`.

As a trivial thought experiment, if you run `-save:` and then terminate your app, on next launch your modified data will still be available. If you run `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` and then terminate your app, any of your local changes will be lost.

Comment: So it's best to use refreshObject, and in appWillResignActive to call -save: ?

Comment: @Devfly: No. I'm rather confused as to why you think `-refreshObject:` is remotely appropriate to use before saving.

Comment: @Devfly: You use `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` if you know the object changed from another context, and you want the changes to be visible in the current context. That's it.

Comment: Isn't the context one per persistent store? Whatever, thanks that was what I needed to hear! :)

Comment: @Devfly: No. A common setup is one context per thread, but you can have as many contexts as you want all accessing the same persistent store.